# Помогите решить проблему с созданием бота в дискорд

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

У меня есть код для кика участника, но он не работает и не выдаёт ошибки:

```
@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx, member, reason):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} был кикнут по причине {reason}')
```

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)